# CircularFIFOQueue : Using get method

Tags: java, queue, fifo

I am trying to implement a CircularFifoQueue in java.

```
Queue<List<String>> rssififo = new CircularFifoQueue<List<String>>(2);
```

I am getting consfused on how to use the get method of the CircularFifoQueue API. The API states

```
public E get(int index)
Returns the element at the specified position in this queue.
Parameters:
index - the position of the element in the queue
Returns:
the element at position index
Throws:
NoSuchElementException - if the requested position is outside the range [0, size)
```

However i cannot seem to be able to use `rssiinfo.get(index)`. The only way get method pops up in my editor (android studio) is if i use `rssiinfo.element().get(0)`.

However the element() method  only returns the first element of the queue. How can i access an element at an arbitrary location in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `rssififo` is of the generic `Queue` type rather than the concrete type `CircularFifoQueue`.
The [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html?is-external=true) interface does not have a get method, only the peek, poll and remove methods. 
If you change the declaration to `CircularFifoQueue` then you can access the get method.

Comment: Thanks. Changing declaration to CircularFifoQueue worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code to

```
CircularFifoQueue<List<String>> rssififo = new CircularFifoQueue<List<String>>(2);
```

CircularFifoQueue have the method get(int index). But CircularFifoQueue implements Queue interface . The interface didnt have the method get(int index). Thats the reason you are unable to use this.